# Loading tab favicons in the DOM of an angular chrome extension is successful but explicit XHR requests fail

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension, cors

I have been working on a chrome extension using Angular 5.

I am able to successfully read favIconUrls from the tabs API, and bind them to the DOM of my popup.html. These icons are downloaded and displayed without issue. An example request is below.

```
Request URL:https://www.gitbook.com/assets/images/logo/favicon.ico?
version=19.7.51
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:104.25.213.20:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
cache-control:public, max-age=14400
cf-cache-status:HIT
cf-ray:xxxxx
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:image/x-icon
date:Mon, 08 Jan 2018 16:43:03 GMT
etag:xxxx
expires:Mon, 08 Jan 2018 20:43:03 GMT
last-modified:Fri, 22 Dec 2017 22:51:08 GMT
server:cloudflare
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
via:1.1 vegur

Request Headers
:authority:www.gitbook.com
:method:GET
:path:/assets/images/logo/favicon.ico?version=19.7.51
:scheme:https
accept:image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-xx;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control:no-cache
cookie:xxx
pragma:no-cache
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

This request is being made by angular's platform-browser module.

I want to base64 encode each favicon image and so have been using the fileReader API to read the favIconUrl and convert it into a base64 encoded dataUrl. This works for some resources and not others (depending on CORS).

An example failed request looks as follows.

```
Request URL:https://www.gitbook.com/assets/images/logo/favicon.ico?version=19.7.51
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Origin:chrome-extension://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
version:19.7.51
```

I understand that this request is being blocked as CORS is preventing the origin (my chrome extension) from retrieving the resource. What I'm struggling to understand is how is the same extension, through angulars platform browser module, able to successfully load the resource inside its DOM? Surely this is also in breach of CORS? The request does not show an origin is being set by platform-browser.

Any help in understanding what is going on would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this might be because it's **Chrome** which actually *implements* CORS - it's the thing which adds the `Origin` request header and checks the `Access-Control-*` response headers.

So maybe Chrome is *effectively* bypassing its own CORS processing, when it's processing a Chrome extension doing default stuff?

Also note that directly retrieving images (even from a different domain) doesn't invoke CORS - CORS is only really invoked when **fetch** is used (XMLHttpRequest is basically a 'wrapper' to fetch). So if the fileReader API implements fetch (whether via XMLHttpRequest or directly), then Chrome will invoke its CORS processing.

Comment: Thanks @roryhewitt that helps a lot. Your point around img elements not invoking CORS hit the nail on the head and helped me better understand what was going on. I have read around a bit more now in the associated MDN documentation, specifically CORS on images https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img and tainted canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#What_is_a_tainted_canvas.